# Bootstrap Mobile scroll down, browser url bar didn't hide

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website, use bootstrap framework,

My problems are

1. when I scroll down content, top browser search bar didn't hide.(iPhone)
2. When I click top of screen, page didn't auto scroll to top.
3. When I try to scroll up very fast, it kinds of delay.

Anyone know how to fix this problems?

Here is links
http://hello-walker.com/framework/framework.php

pleas try on iPhone

Comment: Not really clear what the problem is.  Are you talking about the navbar being "fixed" at the top.?

Comment: When we scroll down page on iPhone, Top browser bar usually will auto hide for more space, but its not working on bootstrap

Comment: Include the code you're using here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this plugin. https://github.com/istvan-ujjmeszaros/bootstrap-autohidingnavbar

Add the following code to your page.

`<script>$("div.navbar-fixed-top").autoHidingNavbar();</script>`

Comment: I just found my problem, in my css 
i set html{height:100%; min-height:100%;}
cause I'm using sticky footer, so I may need to remove this css by using media query